# $f(0)=0,\ f'(X)$ is str. increasing: prove that $f(X)/X$ is also increasing function all $X \in(0, \infty)$

Tags: calculus

$f(0)=0, \ f'(X)$ is a strictly increasing function: prove that $f(X)/X$ is also strictly increasing for all $X \in(0, \infty)$

Comment: Could you please define MSIF, and show what work you've done on the problem?

Comment: MSIF is monotonically strictly increasing function .

Comment: I assume f(X)/X as H(X) and differentiate it H'(X) but could able to proof that H'(X) is greater than 0

Comment: What arithmetic error?

Comment: Duplicate of [Show that $x \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing on (0,1) given that f '(x) is strictly increasing on (0,1) and that f(0)=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572489/show-that-x-mapsto-fracfxx-is-strictly-increasing-on-0-1-given-that). Also of [Show that if $f'$ is strictly increasing, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing over $(0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715047/show-that-if-f-is-strictly-increasing-then-fracfxx-is-increasing-ov).

Answer (score 1):

For any $X>0$, $f$ is continuous in $[0,X]$ and differentiable in $(0,X)$. By mean value theorem, there exists $c\in (0,X)$ such that $f'(c)= \frac {f(X)-f(0)} {X-0}=\frac {f(X)} {X}$
Since $f'$ is strictly increasing and $X>c$, we have $f'(X) > f'(c)$, i.e. $ X f'(X) - f(X)>0$

Consider the function $g(X)=\frac {f(X)} X$
$$g'(X)= \frac 1 {X^2} (X f'(X) - f(X))>0$$
So derivative of $g$ is strictly positive. So, $g$ is strictly increasing function.

Comment: Ok I got it . This is absolutely correct

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Apply the mean value theorem to $f$ on the interval $[0, x]$, for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so we've got 2 conditions:

1. $f(0) = 0$
2. $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing

Define $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$. Then as you suggested, taking the derivative yields:
$$h'(x) = \frac{x f'(x) - f(x)}{x^2}$$

We want to show that $h(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$. To see this, note that by the fundamental theorem of calculus and condition $1$ we have:
$$f(x) = \int_{0}^x f'(t)dt$$
Then by the mean value theorem, we have that there is some $c \in (0,x)$ such that:
$$ \int_{0}^x f'(t)dt = xf'(c)$$
By condition $2$, since $c < x$ we have $f'(c) < f'(x)$. Combining this with the above yeilds:
$$f(x) < xf'(x)$$

And now we can complete our proof! The above inequality gives us that $xf'(x) - f(x) > 0$, and for any positive $x$ we know that $x^2 > 0$. Thus, both the numerator and denominator of $h'(x)$ are positive, and therefore $h'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$.

Therefore $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: It is also correct .now I understand it perfectly